# nodejs handlebars error TypeError: this.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

hey smart people that want to help me!

im a nodejs beginner and i want to use handlebars as my template engine...
this is my first nodejs application, i follow this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5ribwPpIPw

i use cloud9 as my ide..

i have only one js file its realy everything:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var hbs = require('express3-handlebars');

app.engine = ('handlebars', hbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set = ('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req,res){
  res.render('index');
});

app.use('/views',express.static('views'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0");
```

im doing everything that the guide refernce me to do... 
[this is my folder tree:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvbCe.jpg)

update: this is the error that i get.. forgot to put it here:

/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:421
  return Boolean(this.set(setting));
                      ^

TypeError: this.set is not a function
    at EventEmitter.enabled (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:421:23)
    at EventEmitter.lazyrouter (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:139:27)
    at EventEmitter.methods.forEach.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:478:10)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:441:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix these lines :

```
app.engine('handlebars', hbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

And for another, change `layout.hbs` to `layout.handlerbars`

Comment: hey thank you very much for helping me.. i fixed the .hbs but it is not the problem.. i know i have problems with my template engine reference but it is actually the same as the one the my guide has.. and it is working for him.. can you be more specific on what to fix?

Comment: @GevAlter Did you fix those line I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - 'express3-handlebars' has been changed to just 'express-handlebars'. You may want to update that. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express3-handlebars).

Also, if you want to name your layouts with a .hbs extension, you can.

```
app.engine('handlebars', hbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout' , extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```